# python error message: TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a class, but I have this error:

```
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is my code:

```
class School:
    def search(self):
        ... # do some stuff

harva = School()    
School.search()
```

Comment: what exaclty is "Ecole"? I can't see where you define it.

Comment: Can you tell me, on which line the error is raising?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails to run: `Ecole` is not defined; it's named as a class.

Comment: "Ecole" is French for "School"; I changed the identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean `harva.search()` instead of `School.search()`.
You defined search as an instance method. You must call it on an instance of school, and not on School class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your final line is incorrect: you must (il faut que vous) invoke an instance method by calling it with an instance, not with the class:

```
harva.search()
```

When you call the method as a *class* method, it needs the instance:

```
School.search(harva)
```

However, you should use the first version.

---

In the future, don't write so much code at once.  You should try to invoke the method before you have written all of that.

Answer (score 0):

In object-oriented programming...the basic fundamental element is an **object** and a class along with its `member variables` & `member functions` can only be accessed through an instance of that class i.e again **object**.

```
class School():
   def search(self):
   ...#some code

harva = School()
harva.search()
```

You can access a function inside a class without creating an instance of that class.
Such functions are called as `static functions.`